# a GUI to monitor thousands threads

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, mono

For academic purposes I've realized a C# library that implements "computation with agents", thinking for example to what JADE does. With this library I can implement a distributed computation algorithm easily. Every agent is an object having a different thread implementing a part of the computation, while the object itself remains free to receive and dispatch messages.
These algorithms can run thousands agents (so threads), monitored by a super-agent that changes their status and synchronize them: I cannot create 10.000 threads and let them run all together, because PC could die...
So every agent has a changing status that I should draw on a GUI to let user realize what is happening during computation. And my agents can be created and killed during computation too, making it harder...
I thought to use a grid in which every cell is an agent, changing background color of every cell according to agent status, but I'm not sure how to "join" single agent to a cell (remember I cannot use an index, because agents number can change and some agent could be destroyed; I thought to create a Control for every new agent and place this Control in the GUI, so I can quickly create, place and destroy it when needed.
The big deal is the huge number of threads and the need to refresh GUI as quick as possible, because threads status change continuously and very quickly.
What can you suggest? What is the best way to accomplish my task?

**UPDATE:** I'm developing this library using Framework 2.0 because it MUST run under Linux too using Mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a central synchronized hashmap that maps thread id -> GUI element.
In this way the super-agent can do changes to the GUI, create new threads and atomically update the hashmap (e.g. this allows reusing GUI elements for new threads). This will obviously cause some read contention on the hashmap when the super-agent gets a lock to update it.

edit: actually you can even get rid of the hashmap and just have an array because the maximum number of threads you can have is quite low (< 2^16), I guess. This would also get rid of the contention, because you could lock single array elements instead of the whole hashmap.

edit2: It actually just occurred to me that you can get rid of everything. Just have a shared surface of 256x256 pixels (i.e. 2^16 pixels). Each pixel belongs to the thread whose threadID is equal to the pixel index. This way each thread only accesses its own pixel. Then create a custom control and have the OnPaint method blit the shared surface to the graphic surface.

Comment: I'm worried that, having thousands threads, searching a hashmap to find the right thread id on every status changing could destroy performances...
Anyway, which kind of control should I use (in you opinion) in GUI to have a really fast update?

Comment: Read my edit above for the hashmap issue. I don't know .NET controls enough to say which to pick for such needs. If I were to guess I kinda recall that there's some control that gives you an empty surface you can draw on. My best bet would be using double buffering and draw operations coalescing on such a surface.

Comment: @CAFxX: so you're telling me to create an empty array (fixed length or not? For better performances is will be better, right?) in which to store thread-id? But I still need to search it before every update.
It's not so clear to me, sorry... can you tell me more or provide an example? Thanks, your suggestion seems the right one....

Comment: Have a fixed array where array[tID] returns a reference to the GUI control for thread tID. Then choose what kind of locking granularity is better for your needs (array-level, element-level, other) so that the super-agent doesn't modify an element while an agent is reading it.

Comment: It actually just occurred to me that you can get rid of everything. Just have a shared surface of 256x256 pixels (i.e. 2^16 pixels). Each pixel belongs to the thread whose threadID is equal to the pixel index. This way each thread only accesses its own pixel. Then create a custom control and have the OnPaint method blit the shared surface to the graphic surface.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with an Infragistics WinGrid in unbound mode. This way you can easily connect the agent-object with the tag of a cell and find the cell by searching for the tags. I would not suggest you to use a single control for each agent because you might experience heavy performance issues!

Comment: Yes, but I think that the "search" part, having thousands threads, could destroy performances... or not ?!?
That grid is not free... well, I prefer using standard components.

Answer (score 0):

I Wouldn't do this in .NET purely, for the farmewok is nearly not powerfull enough for that. Resort to MFC or better Direct3D or, if you need Linux-Support, OpenGL. That might be a overhead but you definitly won't run into update problems(at least not in the GUI)